# Intelli: How to apply custom highlighting to the `await` keyword?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'd like to implement some custom coloring/highlighting of the `await` keyword in the Typescript project I'm currently working on.

I've looked in `File | Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | TypeScript` (and Javascript), but it seems you can only customise to the level of "Keyword", nothing finer grained than that.

How can I customise the look (bold, color, etc.) of *only* the `await` keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For keyword highlighting could be used plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12895-comments-highlighter.

Here is the request to implement this in IDE: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5473
It is shelved for now.